# How do I write a sequential channel composition?

Tags: symbols

Usually for the composition between two channels I write

```
\begin{equation}
    \~ {\mathcal{U}} = \mathcal{D}\circ\mathcal{U}
\end{equation}
```

which gives this

[image]

Now if I write

```
\begin{equation}
    \bigcirc^{n}_{i=1}\CMcal{E}_{i}(\rho) = \CMcal{E}_n\circ\dots\circ\CMcal{E}_{1}(\rho),
\end{equation}
```

gives me this
[image]
but the problem is the exponent n and i=1 aren't directly above and below the circle like you'd get with a \sum^{n}_{i=1}. What I want is something like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write in the preamble:

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Circ}{\bigcirc}
```

and use this:

```
\begin{equation}
    \Circ^{n}_{i=1}\mathcal{E}_{i}(\rho) = \mathcal{E}_n\circ\dots\circ\mathcal{E}_{1}(\rho),
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But why does that work??

Comment: This works because `\DeclareMathOperator*` defines the argument to be an object that behaves like `\Sum` meaning that if it is used in a display, the limits will be set above and below.  If the asterisk is omitted, only sub- and superscript positioning will be used.